# How to find the number of transposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I just learning the abstract algebra now, I'm stuck to find how many transpositions can be made from $(1\ 8)(2)(3\ 6\ 4)(5\ 7)$?

Comment: hint: (364) = (34)(36)

Comment: Oh, I realize that (18)(2)(36)(34)(57) , and I know that transposition is 2-cycle distinct . But because there is (2), it means there are 4 transpositions? so the permutation is even?

Comment: you can omit (2), since it doesnt change anything. just like you can add (9)

Comment: So, the answer is 4, right? I'm sorry for asking this, because I'm very beginner at abstract algebra, but this is so interesting. Anyway could you post your comment as an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it seems like you have it.

$(1\ 8)(2)(3\ 6\ 4)(5\ 7) = (1\ 8)(2)(3\ 4)(3\ 6)(5\ 7) = (1\ 8)(3\ 4)(3\ 6)(5\ 7) $

We can ommit $(2)$ as it simply fixes that element, so you have a product of 4 transpositions